# React Native & i18n returns to default language after routing to another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native with i18n language manager, and I'm trying to create language choice on first app launch.

[image: first screen launch]

The language selection screen does work, after choosing language the component re-renders and execute the correct language. (Assuming I selected English, the buttons string is in English)

[image: Re rendering]

But after signing in to the app the language changes, and I can't really understand why.
(Here suppose to be in English, instead displays the Hebrew string)

[image]

Here is App.js file, I have used `Async Storage` to check if the app has launched before (If didn't show language selection, if did use the saved language choice).

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Login from "./login.js";
import Register from "./register.js";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard.js";
import i18n from "./translation.js";
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { Text, View, Button, I18nManager } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";



const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const HAS_LAUNCHED = "hasLaunched";
const ENGLISH = "en";
const HEBREW = "he";


//Save the language as AsyncStorage for other times the user will open the app
async function setAppLaunched(en) {
  AsyncStorage.setItem(HAS_LAUNCHED, "true");
  AsyncStorage.setItem(en ? ENGLISH : HEBREW, "true");
  if(await AsyncStorage.getItem(HEBREW)){
    i18n.locale = "he";
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
  }
  else{
    i18n.locale = "en";
    I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
  }
}


//If first launch show this screen
function CheckIfFirstLaunch({ onSelect }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const selectLaunched = (value) => {
    if(value){
      i18n.locale = "en";
      I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
    }
    else{
      i18n.locale = "he";
      I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    }
    setAppLaunched(value);
    onSelect();
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };


  return (
    <View>
        <Text>Choose Language</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(false)} title="Hebrew"/>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(true)} title="English"/>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const verifyHasLaunched = async () => {
    try {
      const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED);
      console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED));
      if(hasLaunched){
        setSelected(true);
      }
      else{
        setSelected(false);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setSelected(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => verifyHasLaunched, []);


  if(selected){
    const verifyLang = async () => {
      const lang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('he');
      if(lang != null){
        i18n.locale = "he";
        I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
      }
      else{
        i18n.locale = "en";
        I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
      }
   };
   () => verifyLang;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName={selected ? "Login" : "Language"}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Language" >
          {props => (<CheckIfFirstLaunch {...props} onSelect={() => setSelected(true)} />)}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

translation.js

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import en from './locale/en.json';
import he from './locale/he.json';

i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, he };


export default i18n;
```

I have debugged the values from `AsyncStorage` and received the correct values.

As it seems, the `Async Storage` saves the language data for the re-render of `App.js` file, but the I18n reset his settings after screen routing. Why is that?

How to set language for the entire app on first app launch using React Native?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-river-jd7y8?file=/src/login.js)

Comment: Can you setup a stackblitz/codesandbox for this?

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-river-jd7y8?file=/src/login.js
Not sure if I shared it right, first time I'm using codesandbox (Choose english, and then press register)

Comment: if you want your app to re-render easier, you should use `useContext` hook and save the language there. this hook got something like an automatic `useEffect` and will take place everytime you change the language and set it in `useContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mclean-ctk5p?file=/src/App.js

There are several changes.

The problem came from the fact that each time you selected a language you were setting it as a key in the storage.

Once you've selected English, reloaded and selected Hebrew you get both keys in the storage like this

```
{'he': true, 'en': true}
```

At this point this part always sets the lang to Hebrew cause indeed there is such key ('he' is true).

```
 const verifyLang = async () => {
      const lang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('he');
      if(lang != null){
        i18n.locale = "he";
        I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
       }
```

What I changed is that we no longer set each language as a key. Instead we pass down through `selectLaunched` the languge itself. Then we save it in a `lang` key in the storage. This way the `lang` key always has the correct language stored - 'he' or 'en'.

The `verifyLang` can be removed as it's no longer needed. Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Just tested your sandbox, it re-renders the opposite language on language choice, only once navigating to another screen it works. I can't see why is that happening, any idea?

Comment: fixed, I had `if (value === HEBREW) {18n.locale = "en";` typo. Should be working now.